# Transform doubly linked list

Tags: java, list, transform, nodes

I need to transform the DLL in this way:
Given n (number of nodes), and four integers (a, b, c, d) representing the two intervals a,b and b,c. For example:

```
N: 7

Input list:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

a,b = 2 3
c,d = 5 6
```

What i need to do is to swap the nodes from the given intervals, so the output should be this:

```
1 **5 6** 4 **2 3** 7
```

As you can see the nodes with elements 2 and 3 swapped the places with 5 and 6.

Other way of entering the input can be something like this:

```
N:5

Input: 10 50 40 25 1

a, b: 10 10
c, d: 40 1

Output: 40 25 1 50 10
```

This means that the interval can begin and end at the same number.

EDIT: Note that the intervals can be different i.e. a,b can have 3 nodes and c,d can have more or less, or the same number of nodes.

Here is what I've done so far. I just took the given nodes (a,b,c,d) successors and predecessors, but i need to swap them somehow. Here is the code of the function.

```
private static DLL<Integer> intervals(DLL<Integer> list, int a, int b, int c, int d) {


        DLLNode<Integer> temp = lista.getFirst();
        DLLNode<Integer> temp1;
        DLLNode<Integer> temp2;
        DLLNode<Integer> temp3;
        DLLNode<Integer> temp4;
        while(temp != null){
            if(temp.element == a){
                temp1 = temp.pred;
            }
            if(temp.element == b){
                temp2 = temp.succ;
            }
            if(temp.element == c){
                temp3 = temp.pred;
            }
            if(temp.element == d){
                temp4 = temp.succ;
            }
            temp = temp.succ;
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: What should happen if `b - a > 1`? Is `b - a = d - c` guaranteed?

Comment: Is [this](http://i.imgur.com/s67DgFx.png) a correct interpretation of what the function should do?

Comment: I think you didn't understand it well. The intervals should consist of the elements values, not position.

Comment: yes @Mauris that's the correct

Answer (score 0):

You can do following before returning the list.

```
DLLNode<Integer> a = temp1.succ;
DLLNode<Integer> b = temp2.pred;
DLLNode<Integer> c = temp3.succ;
DLLNode<Integer> d = temp4.pred;

temp1.succ = temp3.succ;
temp3.pred = temp1;

temp4.succ = a;
a.pred = temp4;

b.succ = c;
c.pred = b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close! Suppose the list looks like this:

```
[ ... p, a ... b, q ... r, c ... d, s ... ]
         ^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^
```

You've already extracted the nodes containing `p, q, r, s`. Now you want to swap the underlined regions. Make `p = a.pred` point its `succ` to `c` and vice versa. Similarly, link `d` to `q`; then link `r` to `a` and `b` to `s`.

Comment: I think that we missed one case... what if the first node contains the element? Then temp1 = temp.pred will be null...

Comment: You'll have to handle that manually, or you could add [sentinel nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Using_sentinel_nodes) to both ends of the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, i solved it here is the full code, it's easy for understanding it.

```
private static DLL<Integer> intervals(DLL<Integer> list, int a, int b, int c, int d) {



        DLLNode<Integer> temp =l ist.getFirst();
        DLL<Integer> tmp2=new DLL<Integer>();
        DLL<Integer> tmp3=new DLL<Integer>();
        DLL<Integer> tmp4=new DLL<Integer>();
        DLL<Integer> newList =new DLL<Integer>();
        while(temp .element!=a)
        {
            nova.insertLast(temp .element);
            temp = temp.succ;
        }
        tmp2.insertLast(temp.element);
        temp =temp.succ;
        while(temp.pred.element!=b)
        {
            tmp2.insertLast(temp.element);
            temp=temp.succ;
        }
        while(temp.element!=c)
        {
            tmp3.insertLast(temp.element);
            pom=pom.succ;
        }
        while(temp!=null&&temp.pred.element!=d)
        {
            tmp4.insertLast(temp.element);
            temp=temp.succ;
        }

        DLLNode<Integer> node2=tmp2.getFirst();
        DLLNode<Integer> node3=tmp3.getFirst();
        DLLNode<Integer> node4=tmp4.getFirst();

        while(node4 != null)
        {
            newList.insertLast(node4.element);
            node4=node4.succ;
        }
        while(node3 != null)
        {
            newList.insertLast(node3.element);
            node3=node3.succ;
        }
        while(node2 != null)
        {
            newList.insertLast(node2.element);
            node2=node2.succ;
        }
        while(pom != null)
        {
            newList.insertLast(pom.element);
            pom=pom.succ;
        }
        list = newList;
        return list;
    }
```